# Error when restore database using dialog - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore

I'm trying to restore backups for a DB, but every time I select the files, like this:

[image: restore dialog]

As soon as I click on "Options" or on "Script" (not even to execute the actual restore!), I get the following error:

"An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch".

[image: Error]

Any ideas of what can be happening? If I select only the Full Backup, it works, but it doesn't work if I select all the Transaction Logs.

It's also weird that the backups are not sorted by date & time. If I recall correctly it used to let you even select the exact point in time for recovery.

Am I doing something wrong? Does that mean a backup might be corrupted (if so, how do I check that)?

All backups are performed using Hallengren's script and are checked, verified and compressed.

**UPDATE:**

I did a Profiler and saw that the error happens when this statement is executed: `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM  DISK= '....`

And the next error is displayed:

```
Msg 3231, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The media loaded on "C:\restore-temp\SQL02_Database_FULL_20180827_051921.bak" is formatted to support 1 media families, but 11 media families are expected according to the backup device specification.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
```

**UPDATE 2:** ***(PARTIAL SOLUTION)***

It works if I restore the files one by one. So it's not a problem with the files, but rather with the SSMS. For some reason I cannot select multiple files in the Restore dialog. It used to work, not sure what changed..

Comment: Have you checked SQL Server error log to see if you have more details?

Comment: And what version of SQL Management Studio are you using? Some versions have bugs.

Comment: Thanks @DaniellePaquette-Harvey. Added info that might be important.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086022/backup-failed-for-server-the-media-is-formatted-to-support-2-media-families-err

Comment: Yes thank you. With the added information it adds a new bunch of search possibilities. I'll post the answer here anyway when I find it.

Comment: Looks like SQL server unable to access files..  do you permissions on files?

Comment: @CR241 yes. Actually I'm trying it right now and it works if I restore one by one. So it's not a problem with the files, but rather with the SSMS. For some reason I cannot select multiple files in the Restore dialog. It used to work, not sure what changed...

Comment: check this might help: https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=70927&sliceId=1